# ¿ como hago responsive en mi div?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, responsive

hola tengo este problema, que cuando aumento el tamaño de la pagina a 150+ estos se estiran los cuadros. Como evito, ya habia solucionado un problema con con ayuda media only screen and (max-width:1000px). Ahora encuentro mas problema, :(

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
    <div class="container-xxl py-5">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="text-center mx-auto wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s" style="max-width: 600px">
          <p class="fw-medium text-uppercase text-primary mb-2">
            Nuestro Equipo
          </p>
          <h1 class="display-5 mb-5">Miembros del equipo</h1>
        </div>
    <div class="row g-4">
     <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-6 wow fadeInUp" data-wow-delay="0.1s">
            <div class="team-item">
              <img class="img-fluid" style="width: 5000px; height: 300px" src="img/asesoria_sede_u_chiloe/3.png" alt=""/>
              <div class="d-flex">
                <div class="flex-shrink-0 btn-square bg-primary" style="width: 90px; height: 90px">
                  <i class="fa fa-2x fa-share text-white"></i>
                </div>
                <div
                  class="position-relative overflow-hidden bg-light d-flex flex-column justify-content-center w-100 ps-4"
                  style="height: 90px"
                >
                  <h5>Trabajadores en Obra</h5>
                  <span class="text-primary"
                    >Realización de Obras y Asesorías en Sede Universitaria
                    Chiloé</span
                  >
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema está porque se estás dando un height: 90px

```
<div class="position-relative overflow-hidden bg-light d-flex flex-column justify-content-center w-100 ps-4" 
style="height: auto">
```

Aunque en este caso, lo mejor sería colocarle los media query que se adaptan a cualquier dimesion de la pantalla:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
 div{
  width: (los pixeles que veas);
  height: (los pixeles que veas);
 }
}
```

Otra opción sería implemente quitarle los height y los width y así no obligas al bloque a tener un estilo en duro.

Comment: cada vez que agrego height: auto, y aumento el tamaño d la letra el cuadro blanco se amplia, saliendo del margen

Comment: Claro, porque estás forzando al bloque a salirse del col-md-6 o col-lg-4 por lo que se  pierde el posicionamiento. **Lo mejor es trabajarlo bajo las dimensiones, con los media queries también puedes ir modificando el tamaño de la letra a medida que va cambiando la dimesión de la pantalla.**

Comment: vale pa muchas gracias:)